# Sending UPD packages from Azure Web App to statsD

Tags: sockets, azure, networking, azure-webjobs, statsd

I'm trying to gather some statistic from our web applications. We're hosting our applications on Azure. It's usually Web App resource which is containing one or many web jobs. 
For monitoring tools I'm using:

- statsD.JustEat nuget package (C# client which is sending statistics using UDP)
- telegraf - hosted on Ubuntu virtual machine, gathers data and each x seconds write them to influxDb. Is listening on 8125 port.

That's the overview:
[overview diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNcFv.png)
The problem I'm having: when application is hosted as Web Job in Azure, I'm not able to send any UPD package to telegraf. I'm also not able to get any exception or any log telling me what happened. 
I was trying to send some statistic:

- for host (Public Ip of my virtual machine):8125 port
- for host (Private Ip of my virtual machine):8125 port

With those scenario:

- Console app - external network - public Ip -> works perfectly !
- Web Job (connected to VNET) - public Ip -> doesn't work ! (that's most surprising)
- Web Job (connected to VNET) - private Ip -> doesn't work !
- Web Job (disconnected to VNET) - public Ip -> doesn't work !

Does Azure have some limitations ? The vnet has also Inbound an Outbound rules to free 8125 port (see overview).
Do you have any ideas why this should be failing or do you know any tools which I could use, just to investigate this more ?
Thanks for help !

Comment: You should have a look at Application Insights, There is a free subscription and works great with Azure. you can monitor web app and web job : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/

Comment: The reason it was failing was in statsD client package. There must me something in here (https://github.com/justeat/JustEat.StatsD/blob/master/src/JustEat.StatsD/StatsDUdpClient.cs) which is failing on Azure. When I've switched to different client it was working.